# What's the difference between Google Chrome 10 BETA on dedicated and integrated graphics?

Tags: google-chrome

They say Google Chrome 10 uses the pc's gpu now. But what about the integrated graphics processing?

Comment: What about it? Using the hardware to render graphics is obviously going to be faster than doing it in software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript performance improvement is totally independent of GPU acceleration for rendering.

GPU acceleration is used only for rendering (it's kind of same technique as with Windows' Aero or Apple's Quartz). It's not heavy graphics processing, so IGPs will do fine.

Comment: I changed my question dramatically, I think you saw the old post. Read the question again, just in case.

Answer (score -1):

Integrated graphics just means that the GPU is integrated with the motherboard. In theory it should use the GPU for certain processing.  You still have a GPU, it's just built into the chipset of the motherboard and using system memory for video memory.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit#Integrated_graphics_solutions

Comment: Doesn't exactly answer the question

Comment: It's rather difficult to answer an ambiguous question.

Comment: What about Bob?